# Сервер не отображает веб-страницу ASP.NET Core

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-mvc, сеть, хостинг

Сервер на Ubuntu не отображает веб-страницу. Настроен, вроде как, корректно.

Прописан файл default для nginx, который перенаправляет определенный порт на приложение ASP.NET:

[image: Файл default]

Процессы запущены:
[image: Процессы]

Сервис с приложением также запущен:
[image: Сервис]

Однако, почему-то при попытке перейти по IP-адресу облачного сервера, выводится сообщение, что сервер не позволяет установить соединение, однако, в недалеком прошлом, пока я не перезапустил nginx и сервис, выдавало 502 Bad Gateway. В чем может быть проблема, подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Читайте в логах nginx, почему он решил выдать ошибку 502

Comment: Перенаправляет на https://89.111.170.109:5001/, кстати. И конфигурацию желательно выкладывать текстом, а не картинками.

Comment: @andreymal не подскажите, как настроить логи nginx? просто не могу их найти нигде

Comment: @void при переходе по 89.111.170.109:5001 такая же ошибка - Не удается получить доступ к сайту

Comment: @NewbutBlue я про 5001 к тому, что у вас там все же акцент на 5000 в вопросе. Я к сведению написал.

Comment: @void понял, благодарю. попробую за это зацепиться и поискать